# How to change height for individual cell at section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one issues, i want to change size for specific cell at the section.

Example:

[image]

As you can see at the pictures, i want to change cell size for second Table views section for first cell.

How my cell have fixed height value.

[image]

And i want change cell height depends of the screen resolution, i have module which detect at which device app run, and for example if this is iPhone X i want to change this cell size to **300**

How i can do this?

Comment: You question is not clear. When do you want to change the height? And how do you set the height now?

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri update

Comment: Implement height using `heightForRowAt` delegate.

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri this i know, but how i can change only height only for one cell at the section 2

Comment: Andrew, are you trying to dynamically adjust this cell to fill the complete screen height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this programmatically by conforming to the the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in your `ViewController` and implement the bellow code. Hope this helps...

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourFirstCell", for: indexPath) as? YourFirstCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourSecondCell", for: indexPath) as? YourSecondCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            return cell
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 50
        } else {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                return checkRowHeight()
            } else {
                return 50
            }
        }
    }

    func checkUserPhone() -> Int {
        var rowHeight = Int()
        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1136:
                print("iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C")
                rowHeight = 202
            case 1334:
                print("iPhone 6/6S/7/8")
                rowHeight = 202
            case 1920, 2208:
                print("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+")
                rowHeight = 202
            case 2436:
                print("iPhone X, Xs")
                rowHeight = 300
            case 2688:
                print("iPhone Xs Max")
                rowHeight = 300
            case 1792:
                print("iPhone Xr")
                rowHeight = 300
            default:
                print("unknown")
                rowHeight = 202
            }
        }
        return rowHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: That some work you did here. :-)

Comment: Please can you clarify on your question? At the moment from my understanding you want the cells in the first section to be one size, the first cell in the second second to vary depending on the users iPhone model and then for the remaining cells to be another value?

Comment: @Andrew You can't just change the question after you get an answer. If you got help, accept it and ask your different questions in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can set size here as you want

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}
```